# Manage all abstract methods

Tags: java, abstract, extends

I've created one abstract class named Creature and two classes that extend Creature named Human and Dog. There are also some methods like getAge and setAge, as you can see:

```
public abstract class Creature {
    public abstract void born(String name);
    public abstract void setName(String name);
    public abstract void setAge(int age);
    public abstract int getAge();
    public abstract String getName();
}

public class Human extends Creature {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void born(String name){
        setName(name);
        setAge(0);
    }

// getters and setters
}


public class Dog extends Creature {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void born(String name){
        setName(name);
        setAge(0);
    }

// getters and setters
}
```

And then I make this:

```
private static Creature creature;

String string = new Random().nextInt(2) == 1 ? "Human" : "Dog";
    if (string.equals("Human")) {
        setCreature(new Human());
    } else {
        setCreature(new Dog());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        creature.born("Name" + i);
    // here are born 5 creatures
    }
    // after one year get all creatures and set their age +1
```

My question is, how can I get all creatures born and after one year set their age with +1?

Comment: What is the definition of _one year_ for you? Do you want to increment the age field with a scheduler?

Comment: Do you want to reach your target without doing persistence?

Comment: No,i just want to get all the creatures born and then to make another method to increases their ages immediately.

Comment: You may reflex a bit, and manage your code to avoid code duplicate, because getetr abd setters are same, and may be in parent class

Comment: It looks like the title has no relation to your real question.

Comment: Why do you have `name` and `age` (+getter and setter) in both classes instead of the base `Creature` class!?

Comment: How many creatures do you think you are creating in that for-loop?

Comment: @RobinTopper i know that's static,let's say i'm creating a for loop in another class,for(int i =0;i<5;i++) new Main().getCreature().born("Name" + 1); then how can i get here all the creatures born and add them in a list and then to make another method,to get all creatures from the list and increase their age?

Comment: This last comment is contradicting the comment on [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840678/7598776). Based on what you just wrote, the current answer would do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that  setCreature add a new creature inside a kind of list

you only have to do is to iterate over the list and increment the age without paying any attention to the type of creature

```
for(Creature c : creatures){
  c.setAge(c.getAge() +1 );
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add the creature class inside a list,i just want to get all the creatures born inside the for loop.

Comment: So how do you store your creatures if not in a list or some other storage container? You need to keep track of them or there is no way to increase their age or get them anyway.